# Google Sheets Query referencing a cell's text

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

When I perform this function, it works:

```
=Query(CRM!1:1085,"Select B where D contains 'FirstName LastName' ",4)
```

When I perform this one, where B31 is where the text "FirstName LastName" is located in the sheet, the output is only ONE of the many results:

```
=Query(CRM!1:1085,"Select B where D contains '&B31&' ",4)
```

I want to be able to use the cell rather than write the quoted text in the formula. This is because I need to quickly replicate the formula for many different values. Also because it needs to be automated in case of changes in the source.

Answer (score 6):

`B31` is interpreted as literal string, when you use just `'B31'`. You need to use double quotes along with single ones and concatenate:

```
'"&B31&"'
```

Comment: Note that you must not add any spaces between the quotes, for "readability".   If B31 = the string "word', without the quotes, then if you had a space between the single and double quotes, you'll end up trying to match something like ' word ', instead of 'word', and it will not match.  You can have spaces on either side of the &, with no adverse effect.